# Postgres returning 0 rows even though data is present

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm running into an issue where Postgres is returning 0 rows on a SELECT call even though data exists in the table. The table has 3 columns - `id, firstname, lastname` Here's my query:

```
SELECT * FROM the_table WHERE id=1234;
```

The `id` is the primary key for that table. This query gives back zero rows even though I know that the data is there.
I also tried doing this query and it worked:

```
SELECT * FROM the_table WHERE firstname='Bob';
```

This query works and gives back the the following data: `id=1234, firstname=Bob and lastname=Hubba`

So it seems like the query on the primary key is having issues. Any thoughts on why this might be happening?

Thanks

UPDATE:
Here's a screenshot of the table:
[image]

SOLVED:
I reindexed the table using `reindex table the_table` and now everything is working fine

Comment: Can you post the output of the describe-table command -- `\d the_table`, I think it is?

Comment: Can you show us a screen shot of the database? It could be that you are querying id but the column is called ID or Id or even iD. These are all different columns in PostgreSQL.

Comment: isn’t id an integer? If so, it must not be enclosed by quotes in your query.

Comment: @greg Yes, I've tried with and without quotes and neither works

Comment: @Maderas Posted a screenshot

Comment: @ruakh Posted a screenshot of the describe-table command

Comment: post result of `SELECT * FROM the_table WHERE lower(id::text)='1234';`?..

Comment: @VaoTsun that gives me 0 rows back

Comment: and if you add explain analyze before?..

Comment: @VaoTsun Its `Seq Scan on the_table  (cost=0.00..52.89 rows=3 width=615) (actual time=2.892..2.892 rows=0 loops=1)
   Filter: (lower(id) = ‘1234’::text)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 531
 Planning time: 0.081 ms
 Execution time: 2.912 ms` The table has 531 rows total btw

Comment: just in case - what the output of `SELECT the_table FROM the_table WHERE firstname='Bob';`?..

Comment: @VaoTsun Its this: `the_table     
------------------
 (1234,Bob,Hubba)
(1 row)`

Comment: BTW I case of the integer `id` the `Filter: (lower(id) = ‘1234’::text)` should to look like `Filter: (lower((id)::text) = '1234'::text)`

Comment: The primary index is probably corrupted, try [`reindex the_table.`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-reindex.html)

Comment: @klin I thought so, but look at the plan - Seq Scan - actual rows=0  :O

Comment: @Abelisto great point! I did not notice. buddy2891 what version you run? you don't modify output - don't you? :)

Comment: @klin I reindexed the table and now its working. thanks!

Comment: You should never need to reindex like this. That indicates either a PostgreSQL bug or some kind of disk/file system corruption. What is your *exact* PostgreSQL version, from `SELECT version()`?